# instagram login error:- Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCWebview when instagram login in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to implement an Instagram login. but when I install react-native-instagram-login npm and place this code

```
import InstagramLogin from 'react-native-instagram-login';
<InstagramLogin
      ref={ref => (this.instagramLogin = ref)}
      appId='your-app-id'
      appSecret='your-app-secret'
      redirectUrl='your-redirect-Url'
      scopes={['user_profile', 'user_media']}
      onLoginSuccess={this.setIgToken}
      onLoginFailure={(data) => console.log(data)}
    />
```

and run this code, get an error -
1.Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCWebview when instagram login in react native
2.Module AppRegistry is not registered callable module (calling runApplication)

how to get rid of this error.
here package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-community/cookies": "^5.0.1",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
"@react-native-community/viewpager": "^5.0.11",
"@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^6.0.0",
"firebase": "^8.6.0",
"html-entities": "^1.3.1",
"lottie-react-native": "^3.5.0",
"native-base": "^2.13.12",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.2",
"react-native-agora": "^3.2.2",
"react-native-animated-loader": "0.0.8",
"react-native-awesome-alerts": "^1.3.3",
"react-native-banner-carousel": "^1.0.3",
"react-native-checkbox-heaven": "^0.1.6",
"react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
"react-native-document-picker": "^5.0.3",
"react-native-fbsdk-next": "^4.1.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
"react-native-get-random-values": "^1.6.0",
"react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
"react-native-image-view": "^2.1.9",
"react-native-image-viewing": "^0.2.0",
"react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
"react-native-instagram-login": "^2.0.4",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
"react-native-login-twitter": "^3.0.4",
"react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
"react-native-media-controls": "^2.3.0",
"react-native-pager-view": "^5.1.6",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.12.0",
"react-native-render-html": "^4.2.3",
"react-native-responsive-dimensions": "^3.1.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.4",
"react-native-screens": "^2.10.1",
"react-native-share": "^3.7.0",
"react-native-shimmer-placeholder": "^1.0.36",
"react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
"react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.2",
"react-native-thumbnail-video": "^0.1.2",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
"react-native-video": "^5.1.1",
"react-native-video-controls": "^2.7.1",
"react-native-web": "^0.13.6",
"react-native-webview": "^11.6.2",
"react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
"react-navigation-drawer": "^2.5.0",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2",
"react-navigation-tabs": "^2.9.0",
"react-redux": "^7.2.1",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"uuid": "^8.3.2"
```

},

Comment: can you please provide your project package.json?

Comment: please check package.json@JigneshMayani

Comment: have a try to remove react-native-render-html

Answer (score 1):

remove "react-native-webview" in "react-native-instagram-login"

rm -rf node_modules/react-native-instagram-login/node_modules/react-native-webview

because duplicate "react-native-webview"

Comment: this worked for me , but i also faced connection issue as my emulator couldn't access internet. in my case it turned out to be my dev environment(windows OS) was corrupted, on fixing it started working(OS reformatting worked for me). But i have seen others fixed it via vpn setting check that out too

Answer (score 0):

run

npm ls react-native-webview

The package may have been installed by another package in my case was flutterwave-react-native@1.0.4

So i removed my react-native-webview and reinstalled with the exact version in
flutterwave-react-native

Answer (score 0):

In package.json, just configure:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "rm -rf node_modules/react-native-instagram-login/node_modules/react-native-webview",
  }
}
```